# How to display in ListView entities with one-to-many relationship

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a context class with 3 DbSets and one-to-many relationships:
(1)Locations - University(many)
(1)University - Rating(many)

And I need to display the result of query to all Ratings in my listview in wpf.
But listView doesn't display fields from University and Location.

[image: ListView]

Query example:

```
  using (var c = new Context())
        {
            ratingListView.ItemsSource = (from w in c.Ratings
                     where w.Year.Value == 2012
                     select w).ToList();
        }
```

ListView bindings:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Rank" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding WorldRank}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Institution" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Unviversity}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Location" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Location }"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="National&#x0a;   Rank" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NationalRank }"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header=" Quality of &#x0a; Education" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding QualityOfEducation}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="  Alumni of &#x0a;Employment" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AlumniEmployment}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header=" Quality of &#x0a;    Faculty" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding QualityOfFaculty}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Publications" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Publications }"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Citations" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Citations }"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header=" Broad &#x0a;Impact" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding BroadImpact}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Patents" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Patents }"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Score" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Score }"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only selected fields from the Ratings table, so how do you expect to be able to display fields from the University and Locations!

**Option 1**:

Bind University and Location columns using navigation objects, such as `University.UniversityName` and `University.Location.LocationName` (I made up the member names as you have not supplied the whole structure of you EF).

**Option 2**:

Include the University and Location in the `linq` query.

```
 using (var c = new Context())
        {
            ratingListView.ItemsSource = (from w in c.Ratings
                                         join u in c.Universities
                                         on w.UniversityID equals u.ID
                                         join loc in c.Locations
                                         on u.LocationID equals loc.ID
                     where w.Year.Value == 2012
                     select new {loc.Location, u.University, w.field1, w.field2}).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Do you have navigation objects in your EDMX file (EF)? If so, option 1 may be the way to go. It is cleaner and neater.

Comment: Fixed the problem you had with Option 2 - now it uses an anonymous type